# Using a Built-In Method in a Class I've Defined in Python

Tags: python, methods

I am trying to use the .split method within my "clean" method definition in my "Time" class. Every time I execute the function I am prompted with the error 'Time' object has no attribute 'split'. Here is what I have so far:

```
def __init__(self, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0):
    '''hours represents time in hours, minutes represents time in
       minutes, and seconds represents time in seconds'''

    self.H = hours
    self.M = minutes
    self.S = seconds
    self.clean()

def clean(self):
    '''Adjust Time object so that the number of seconds and minutes
       is between 0 and 59'''

    if isinstance(self.H,str) == True:
        self.H = self.split(':')
        self.H = self[0]
        self.M = self[1]
        self.S = self[2]
        return self.__str__()

    else:

        self.S = int(self.H * 3600 + self.M * 60 + self.S)

        self.M = int(self.S / 60)
        self.H = int(self.M / 60) 

        self.M = self.M % 60
        self.S = self.S % 60


    return self.__str__()
```

So Time("2:33:04") returns a Time object: 02:33:04
Is there any way around this or do I have to define .split within my Time class?

Comment: `self.split(":")` does not exist. But why not call it on a string object representing time? Also `Time("2:33:04") ` suggest you are passing string to constructor, but you define it as integers? Very confusing your code is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is get the class members H from your Time object and split it. I'm not sure this is a great OO design, but if you must do that, it looks like the problem is you are calling `split` on the class instead of the class member `H`.

So, in the end you should call `self.H.split(':')` if you are storing the time as an encoded string in `H`.

So the code would have to change to:

```
time_attrs = self.split(':')
self.H = time_attrs[0]
self.M = time_attrs[1]
self.S = time_attrs[2]
return self.__str__()
```